# Tesseract iOS - fails to recognize text

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, tesseract

I am trying to integrate tesseract OCR library in my `react native` project for text recognition. I have installed `tesseract iOS` and integrated it successfully. But whenever I try to recognize text I get the following error:

> Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.2018-06-27
>   15:16:10.417392+0500 MyApp[528:165975] No recognized text. Check that
>   -[Tesseract setImage:] is passed an image bigger than 0x0. 2018-06-27 15:16:10.419 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RNTextRecognitionQueue]
>   Exception '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
>   was thrown while invoking readData on target RNTextRecognition with
>   params (
>       "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/630539FD-AFDA-441F-8AB8-98CAA0867CE1/Library/Caches/Camera/F03909D4-4B7C-4A07-88BA-028E5A175156.jpg"
>   )

I am capturing picture using `react-native-camera` and passes the URI to `readData` method. And the trained data being used is from this [repo](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)
This is my code:

```
#import "RNTextRecognition.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>


@implementation RNTextRecognition
  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(readData:(NSString *)uri)
  {
    RCTLogInfo(@"URI %@", uri);
    [self initTesseract:uri];
  }

- (void) initTesseract: (NSString *)uri {
  G8Tesseract *tesseract = [[G8Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
  tesseract.delegate = self;

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:uri];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
  [tesseract setImage:img];
  [tesseract recognize];
  NSLog(@"%@", [tesseract recognizedText]);
}

- (void)progressImageRecognitionForTesseract:(G8Tesseract *)tesseract {
  NSLog(@"progress: %lu", (unsigned long)tesseract.progress);
}

- (BOOL)shouldCancelImageRecognitionForTesseract:(G8Tesseract *)tesseract {
  return NO;
}

-(UIImage *)preprocessedImageForTesseract:(G8Tesseract *)tesseract sourceImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage {
  NSString* text = tesseract.recognizedText;
  NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithString:text]);
  return sourceImage;
}

@end
```

Edit:
After debugging found that the error occurs at the following line in G8Tesseract.mm `setImage` method:

```
UIImage *thresholdedImage = [self.delegate preprocessedImageForTesseract:self sourceImage:image];
```

Comment: To use tesserat you need to add languages [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata) and the error means that image have a mistake, you need call setImage before recognition. Could you check if image isn't nil before setImage?

Comment: @Lito I have added eng language trained data and I've verified that `img` is not nil

Comment: Could you try set this properties: 
`tesseract.charWhitelist = @"0123456789"; 
tesseract.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_sample.jpg"] g8_blackAndWhite];`
And set image on tree project and try with it, or your white list of characters.
This is for simplify the computation process for Tesserat.

Comment: @Lito yes I have even tries using this implementation. I have found the line at which error occurs ... will add it in my question

Comment: I recommend you, obtain the image route with this method: `NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMAGE_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"jpg"];`. The problem apparently it's caused for the way to obtain the image. For that IMAGE_FILE_NAME, you need to obtain the last path of your URI param